# How to set up Docusign Authorization Code Grant RedirectUrl and Working Example Code Walk-through

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Can someone refer me a working example of the C# Authorization Code Grant code to implement docusign with
the authorization code grant flow.  I am following  [this Documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant) which provides a link to [this repository](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core). However the code is not working as after  being prompted to authenticate via the docusign website by logging in, I am not redirected back to http://localhost:8080. The documentation does not clearly explain how to configure for my local environment. I set up my appurl in appsettings.json

```
 AppUrl": "http://localhost:8080"
```

I also set the redirecturl in the app to

> http://localhost:8080/

How can I configure the redirect to go back to my local site?
Is there other blogs or documentation that will walk step by step through the code explaining the different components?

Answer (score 0):

The [Installation Instructions](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core#installation) note that the Redirect URI needs to be `http://localhost:8080/ds/callback` - not just `http://localhost:8080`